# How to pass feature file path with included spaces on command line via karate.options

Tags: karate

On Windows systems, paths with included spaces are allowed. For our framework built on top of Karate, I would like to robustly handle such eventualities. But if there are spaces in the feature file path given to karate.options, Karate interprets the value as multiple paths, as this is [by design](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karateoptions).

So I've already tried enclosing the path with single and double quotes, as well as all possible pairs of parentheses. Unfortunately, none of these seem to work. Is there no syntax to express this intention?

Comment: Yes, we have never gotten that request before - so the best thing for you is to contribute code or find someone who can. I can say that this is not the highest priority for the open-source development team right now.

Comment: Thanks, we are actually already considering this. However, our team is still too small for that and our Java knowledge is unfortunately not deep enough yet. But may be next year ... For now, we're mainly focused on configuration scripts in the Javascript area of Karate.